# Why do I get the wrong result from this program to compute gross pay?

Tags: python

This is actually a homework. Here is the question.

> Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using raw_input to compute gross pay. Pay the hourly rate for the hours up to 40 and 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use raw_input to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number. Do not worry about error checking the user input - assume the user types numbers properly.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rate_hour = raw_input("Enter rate:")
r = float(rate_hour)
if h <= 40:
    r = 1
else :
    r = 1.5
print h * r
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how overtime hours work. Read your questions again.

Comment: I get the wrong answer. So i have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yes, we can see that you get the wrong answer and yes, you have gone wrong somewhere.  You have to pay the hourly rate on the first zero to forty hours, and then pay the overtime rate on hours in excess of forty — that's what the instructions say.  You don't have the correct conditions or calculations in your code.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you are setting hourly rate to 1 and 1.5, after the user has enter the hourly rate.
Secondly you have misunderstood the computation of over time. It should only be applied to hours worked that are over 40. Not all hours.
Here is a rough modification of your code.

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rate_hour = raw_input("Enter rate:")
r = float(rate_hour)
if h <= 40:
    print h * r
else :
    print (40 * r) + (h -40) * r * 1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is -

1. if the person has worked more than 40 hours, you pay him 1.5 times for complete hours worked.
2. if the person has worked less than 40 hours, you pay him 1 times for complete hours worked.

This works correctly if the amount of hours is less than 40, but according to your question, what you have to do is -

1. if the person has worked more than 40 hours, pay 1 times for up to 40 hours, and then 1.5 times after 40 hours (that is `total hours - 40`).

Comment: I understood the mistake but how to implement it in the code?

Comment: Inside your if block, compute the gross pay, rather than the rate . In the if block for less than 40 , gross pay is `hours * rate`.
For if block for greater than 40 , gross pay is `40*rate + (hours -40) * rate * 1.5`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the way you've approached this.

1. The question specifies that the rate of pay only increases after 40 hours are worked, and so if 45 hours are worked, only 5 of those hours earn the overtime rate.

   Look at the way you have written your `if` statement, and you should be able to see an incongruence between your code and the question. In particular, you'll need to look at the `else:` section.
2. When calculating pay using the standard or overtime rate, remember that the new rate will be a function of the old one. You should be able to see in your code that setting `r = 1` or `r = 1.5` will cause a problem. Assuming 10 hours have been worked, your code will produce `10 * 1` instead of `10 * rate_hour`

To help you:

- To modify a variable `number` such that it is doubled, `variable = variable * 2`
- Calculating pay when more than 40 hours are worked will require 2 separate calculations, so you may want to create a variable `pay` under `if:` and `else:`, and then `print` that.

Answer (score 1):

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")

h = float(hrs)

rr=input("enter the rate")

r=float(rr)

if h<=40:

         pay=h*1.5
else:

        pay=(40 * r) + (h -40) * r * 1.5

print(pay)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = input('Enter Hours')
rate = input('Enter Rate')

hours = float(hours)
rate = float(rate)

if (hours) > 40:
    pay = (((hours - 40) * 1.5) * rate) + 40 * rate
    print (pay)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23050037)

Answer (score 0):

```
score=input("Please type a score between 0.0 and 1.0:")
```

try:

```
float(score)

  if float(score) >= 0.9 and float(score) <= 1.0:

    print("A")

  elif float(score) >= 0.8 and float(score) <= 0.9:

    print("B")

  elif float(score) >= 0.7 and float(score) <= 0.8:

    print("C")

  elif float(score) >= 0.6 and float(score) <= 0.7:

    print("D")

  elif float(score) > 0 and float(score) <= 0.6:

    print("F")

  else:

    print("Bad score.  Please run the program again.")

except:

    print("Bad score.  Please run the program again.")
```